# How to get live Fedex shipping rate in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, razor

In my shopping cart,i just want to shipping rate of Fedex.

I have `fedex developer access key,test account number and test meter number`.

From above property,how can i get live shipping rate..

Can any one give me step to do that..

Comment: Downloadmore - i'm not familiar with the fedex api, but it sounds like there could well be example usages on their developer portal -no??

Comment: Ya refer fedex developer tool,but i can't get it that how/where to start my coding in asp.net??

Comment: Can you give a sample link ??

Comment: from 'distant' memory, nopCommerce integrates the fedex api. might be an idea to look thro the source of that for pointers

Comment: @Downloadmore you should have just improved your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080746/shipping-webservice-for-asp-net-mvc-razor instead of starting a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register on the Fedex Developer Resource Center [link](http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/index.html)

There, you can find lots of examples and documentation under "Technical Resources" > "FedEx Web Services for Shipping"

More specifically, at the bottom of the "Get started" page, you can download sample projects for the "Rate" API.